# moveit2 not planning: Unable to sample any valid states for goal tree

Tags: moveit, ros-humble, motion-planning, errors

I am relatively new to ros and moveit. I am working in humble on an m1 mac but using a vm to run ubuntu jammy.

I've followed the moveit tutorials and successfully got the panda arm moving to a programmatically specified position, but cannot get it working for the Open-Manipulator arm.

I've almost entirely copied the setup used for the panda arm and launch file here:
https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2_tutorials/blob/humble/doc/tutorials/quickstart_in_rviz/launch/demo.launch.py

But the code continues to fail with this error:
[move_group-4] [ERROR] [1704162265.426817524] [ompl]: ./src/ompl/geometric/planners/rrt/src/RRTConnect.cpp:252 - arm_group/arm_group: Unable to sample any valid states for goal tree

I'm using the hello_moveit program developed in the tutorials, planning to a position found using this code (to ensure it is accessible by the arm): [How to extract position of the gripper in ROS2/MoveIt2](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/103393/how-to-extract-position-of-the-gripper-in-ros2-moveit2)

This is the whole log, if it helps:

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/parallels/.ros/log/2024-01-02-13-23-57-306485-ubuntu-linux-22-04-02-desktop-765762
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
[INFO] [rviz2-1]: process started with pid [765763]
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-2]: process started with pid [765765]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [765767]
[INFO] [move_group-4]: process started with pid [765769]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-5]: process started with pid [765779]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process started with pid [765782]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [765784]
[INFO] [spawner-8]: process started with pid [765787]
[static_transform_publisher-2] [WARN] [1704162237.698825084] []: Old-style arguments are deprecated; see --help for new-style arguments
[static_transform_publisher-2] [INFO] [1704162237.770257746] [static_transform_publisher]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-2] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-2] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-2] from 'world' to 'link1'
[rviz2-1] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1704162238.010827901] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment gripper_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1704162238.010907735] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment gripper_link_sub
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1704162238.010919027] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link1
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1704162238.010922735] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link2
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1704162238.010926027] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link3
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1704162238.010929402] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link4
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1704162238.010932527] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link5
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1704162238.010935861] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment world
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1704162238.029279220] [controller_manager]: [Deprecated] Passing the robot description parameter directly to the control_manager node is deprecated. Use '~/robot_description' topic from 'robot_state_publisher' instead.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162238.042167009] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'FakeSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162238.043017687] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'FakeSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162238.043063188] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'FakeSystem'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162238.043132980] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'FakeSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162238.043148730] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'FakeSystem'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162238.043152064] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'FakeSystem' 
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162238.043154980] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'FakeSystem'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162238.060079113] [controller_manager]: update rate is 100 Hz
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162238.073808747] [controller_manager]: RT kernel is recommended for better performance
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162238.345918222] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.193708 seconds
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162238.354558249] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'open_manipulator_x'...
[rviz2-1] libGL error: pci id for fd 28: 1ab8:0010, driver (null)
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162239.049497334] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162239.106166058] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'arm_group_controller'
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1704162239.125395596] [arm_group_controller]: [Deprecated]: "allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end" is set to true. The default behavior will change to false.
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1704162239.132073139] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162239.134657922] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162239.134718340] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162239.149096148] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'gripper_group_controller'
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1704162239.162577612] [gripper_group_controller]: [Deprecated]: "allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end" is set to true. The default behavior will change to false.
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1704162239.188939158] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1704162239.223769894] [spawner_arm_group_controller]: Loaded arm_group_controller
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162239.232135501] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'arm_group_controller'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162239.232244378] [arm_group_controller]: No specific joint names are used for command interfaces. Using 'joints' parameter.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162239.232265961] [arm_group_controller]: Command interfaces are [position] and state interfaces are [position velocity].
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162239.232276836] [arm_group_controller]: Using 'splines' interpolation method.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162239.232565632] [arm_group_controller]: Controller state will be published at 50.00 Hz.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162239.238247621] [arm_group_controller]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20.00 Hz.
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1704162239.248869632] [spawner_gripper_group_controller]: Loaded gripper_group_controller
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162239.251143244] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'gripper_group_controller'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162239.251224912] [gripper_group_controller]: No specific joint names are used for command interfaces. Using 'joints' parameter.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162239.251239579] [gripper_group_controller]: Command interfaces are [position] and state interfaces are [position velocity].
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162239.251252246] [gripper_group_controller]: Using 'splines' interpolation method.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162239.251427123] [gripper_group_controller]: Controller state will be published at 50.00 Hz.
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1704162239.252312259] [gripper_group_controller]: Action status changes will be monitored at 20.00 Hz.
[rviz2-1] pci id for fd 29: 1ab8:0010, driver (null)
[rviz2-1] libGL error: pci id for fd 32: 1ab8:0010, driver (null)
[ros2_control_node-5] [ERROR] [1704162239.356359130] [controller_manager]: Can't activate controller 'arm_group_controller': Command interface with 'joint1/position' does not exist
[rviz2-1] pci id for fd 33: 1ab8:0010, driver (null)
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1704162239.373751978] [spawner_arm_group_controller]: Configured and activated arm_group_controller
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162239.427708750] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162239.427951337] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Listening to 'joint_states' for joint states
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162239.428477885] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Listening to joint states on topic 'joint_states'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162239.428884224] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162239.428898932] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162239.429451898] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162239.429489440] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting world geometry update monitor for collision objects, attached objects, octomap updates.
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162239.430097239] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'collision_object'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162239.430670788] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[move_group-4] [WARN] [1704162239.437077287] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor.middleware_handle]: Resolution not specified for Octomap. Assuming resolution = 0.1 instead
[ros2_control_node-5] [ERROR] [1704162239.474477973] [controller_manager]: Can't activate controller 'gripper_group_controller': Command interface with 'gripper/position' does not exist
[spawner-8] [INFO] [1704162239.491823736] [spawner_gripper_group_controller]: Configured and activated gripper_group_controller
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1704162239.528172826] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1704162239.528289911] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4 (GLSL 4)
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process has finished cleanly [pid 765782]
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1704162239.579871070] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[move_group-4] libGL error: pci id for fd 11: 1ab8:0010, driver (null)
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process has finished cleanly [pid 765784]
[INFO] [spawner-8]: process has finished cleanly [pid 765787]
[move_group-4] pci id for fd 13: 1ab8:0010, driver (null)
[rviz2-1] Warning: class_loader.impl: SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occurred with plugin factory for class rviz_default_plugins::displays::InteractiveMarkerDisplay. New factory will OVERWRITE existing one. This situation occurs when libraries containing plugins are directly linked against an executable (the one running right now generating this message). Please separate plugins out into their own library or just don't link against the library and use either class_loader::ClassLoader/MultiLibraryClassLoader to open.
[rviz2-1]          at line 253 in /opt/ros/humble/include/class_loader/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.336776828] [moveit.ros.perception.pointcloud_octomap_updater]: Listening to '/head_mount_kinect/depth_registered/points' using message filter with target frame 'world '
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.500803841] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Loading planning pipeline 'ompl'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.541352443] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning interface 'OMPL'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.548432950] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'ompl.path_tolerance' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.548784663] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'ompl.resample_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.548913915] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'ompl.min_angle_change' was not set. Using default value: 0.001000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.549165335] [moveit_ros.fix_workspace_bounds]: Param 'ompl.default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using default value: 10.000000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.549320670] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_bounds_error' was set to 0.100000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.549519464] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.549675049] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.549820385] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'ompl.jiggle_fraction' was not set. Using default value: 0.020000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.549986845] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'ompl.max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.550160597] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Optimal Parameterization'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.550316599] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Resolve constraint frames to robot links'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.550443226] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.550561186] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.550686312] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.550839523] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.554530987] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Loading planning pipeline 'chomp'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.577716575] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning interface 'CHOMP'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.583086352] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'chomp.path_tolerance' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.583605108] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'chomp.resample_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.583844611] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'chomp.min_angle_change' was not set. Using default value: 0.001000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.584013947] [moveit_ros.fix_workspace_bounds]: Param 'chomp.default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using default value: 10.000000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.584188157] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'chomp.start_state_max_bounds_error' was set to 0.100000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.584352701] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'chomp.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.584492703] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'chomp.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.584622830] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'chomp.jiggle_fraction' was not set. Using default value: 0.020000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.584738498] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'chomp.max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.584880500] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Optimal Parameterization'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.585140378] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.585308213] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.589589351] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.589795854] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.590993661] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Loading planning pipeline 'pilz_industrial_motion_planner'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.594708500] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner.joint_limits_aggregator]: Reading limits from namespace robot_description_planning
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.601538088] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Available plugins: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderCIRC pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderLIN pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderPTP 
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.601888009] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderCIRC
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.605974269] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [CIRC]
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.606332024] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderLIN
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.607380912] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [LIN]
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.607555581] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderPTP
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.608529344] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [PTP]
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.608700721] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning interface 'Pilz Industrial Motion Planner'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.614599838] [moveit_ros.fix_workspace_bounds]: Param 'pilz_industrial_motion_planner.default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using default value: 10.000000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.614942342] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'pilz_industrial_motion_planner.start_state_max_bounds_error' was not set. Using default value: 0.050000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.615071886] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'pilz_industrial_motion_planner.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.615211804] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'pilz_industrial_motion_planner.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.615384223] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'pilz_industrial_motion_planner.jiggle_fraction' was not set. Using default value: 0.020000
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.615530475] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'pilz_industrial_motion_planner.max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.615672143] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.615810770] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.615936855] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.616074690] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.752638144] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Added FollowJointTrajectory controller for arm_group_controller
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.755354887] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Added FollowJointTrajectory controller for gripper_group_controller
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.755799018] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 2 controllers in list
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.756034188] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 2 controllers in list
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.756560319] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.760316326] [move_group.move_group]: MoveGroup debug mode is ON
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.804735560] [move_group.move_group]: 
[move_group-4] 
[move_group-4] ********************************************************
[move_group-4] * MoveGroup using: 
[move_group-4] *     - ApplyPlanningSceneService
[move_group-4] *     - ClearOctomapService
[move_group-4] *     - CartesianPathService
[move_group-4] *     - ExecuteTrajectoryAction
[move_group-4] *     - GetPlanningSceneService
[move_group-4] *     - KinematicsService
[move_group-4] *     - MoveAction
[move_group-4] *     - MotionPlanService
[move_group-4] *     - QueryPlannersService
[move_group-4] *     - StateValidationService
[move_group-4] ********************************************************
[move_group-4] 
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.810250798] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_context]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162240.810618094] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_context]: MoveGroup context initialization complete
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/ApplyPlanningSceneService'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/ClearOctomapService'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteTrajectoryAction'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupMoveAction'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPlanService'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupQueryPlannersService'...
[move_group-4] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupStateValidationService'...
[move_group-4] 
[move_group-4] You can start planning now!
[move_group-4] 
[rviz2-1] [ERROR] [1704162243.126133719] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Action server: /recognize_objects not available
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1704162243.198742399] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: MoveGroup namespace changed: / -> . Reloading params.
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1704162243.410870531] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.0792322 seconds
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1704162243.411844544] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'open_manipulator_x'...
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1704162243.909002993] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1704162243.917111680] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/monitored_planning_scene'
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1704162244.099570308] [interactive_marker_display_187651634839072]: Connected on namespace: /rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1704162244.114958797] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: group arm_group
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1704162244.114984339] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'arm_group' in namespace ''
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1704162244.122498894] [move_group_interface]: Ready to take commands for planning group arm_group.
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1704162244.127524625] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: group arm_group
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1704162244.131083878] [interactive_marker_display_187651634839072]: Sending request for interactive markers
[rviz2-1] [INFO] [1704162244.203532598] [interactive_marker_display_187651634839072]: Service response received for initialization
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162260.410965955] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Received request
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162260.411792132] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: executing..
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162260.416575694] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162260.425508518] [moveit.ompl_planning.model_based_planning_context]: Planner configuration 'arm_group' will use planner 'geometric::RRTConnect'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
[move_group-4] [ERROR] [1704162265.426817524] [ompl]: ./src/ompl/geometric/planners/rrt/src/RRTConnect.cpp:252 - arm_group/arm_group: Unable to sample any valid states for goal tree
[move_group-4] [WARN] [1704162265.429267430] [moveit.ompl_planning.model_based_planning_context]: Timed out: 5.0s ≥ 5.0s
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162265.670644595] [moveit.ompl_planning.model_based_planning_context]: Unable to solve the planning problem
[move_group-4] [INFO] [1704162265.671545648] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Timeout reached
```

Comment: It ia often the case that the stdf and the urdf are not in sync, and you are getting spurious collisions because two consecutive joints collide. I think that there is a tab on thr rviz moveit controller that shows you which collision is verified.